# Replacement for NUnitAsp

Tags: asp.net, nunit, webautomation

Are there any replacements for NUnitAsp that anyone knows of for testing ASP.NET pages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) or [IEUnit](http://code.google.com/p/ieunit/).

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Selenium](http://selenium.openqa.org/).

Comment: This project looks unfinished. Documentation is lacking badly.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that both IeUnit and WatiN are discontinued.

Using Selenium directly in tests is not a good idea, as you may probably need to [encapsulate page objects](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/encapsulation-oops-principle/).

I'd recommend to use the **[Playwright for .NET](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/)** as a web UI automation test tool.

You may also consider using one of these tools:

- [Atata Framework](https://github.com/atata-framework/atata)
- [Canopy](http://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/) (F#)
- [Coypu](https://github.com/featurist/coypu)
- [Test.Automation](https://github.com/ObjectivityLtd/Test.Automation)
- [TestStack.Seleno](http://seleno.teststack.net/)

## See also

See also the list of Web Application Testing frameworks for .NET that is maintained and up-to-date:

- [List of Automated Testing Tools and Frameworks for .NET: Web Application Testing](https://github.com/dariusz-wozniak/List-of-Testing-Tools-and-Frameworks-for-.NET/blob/master/README.md#web-application-testing).